# Do geodesics on a hyperkähler quotient have nice lifts?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, geodesics, quaternionic-geometry

Suppose one has a flat quaternionic vector space $V$, with a compatible inner product $g$. So $(V,g)$ is a flat hyperkähler manifold. Assume that there is some compact Lie group $G$ acting on $V$ isometrically and triholomorphically, and that the action is hamiltonian. Let $M$ be the hyperkähler quotient $V//G$. I am interested in studying the geodesics of $M$. Is there a nice description of these geodesics, using say $V$ and the moment map? For instance, let us start with a point $x \in M$, and let us choose a lift $\hat{x} \in \mu^{-1}(0)$ of $x$, where

$\mu: V \to \mathfrak{g}^* \otimes \mathbb{R}^3$

is the moment map. Note that $\hat{x}$ is determined up to the action of $G$. Let $v \in T_x(M)$ be a unit tangent vector at $x$. Let $\hat{v}$ be the unique tangent vector at $\hat{x}$ which is a lift of $v$ and which is orthogonal to $G(\hat{x})$, the orbit of $G$ containing $\hat{x}$.

Similarly, any curve $\gamma(t)$ in M, for $t \in (-\epsilon, \epsilon)$, passing through $x$ at $t=0$, and say parametrized by arclength, can be lifted to a unique curve $\hat{\gamma}(t)$ in $\mu^{-1}(0)$ passing through $\hat{x}$ at $t=0$, such that $\hat{\gamma}'(t)$ is a lift of $\gamma'(t)$ which is orthogonal to the orbit $G(\hat{\gamma}(t))$.

In particular, a geodesic $\gamma(t)$ passing through $x$ at $t=0$ with initial velocity $v$ can also be lifted to a curve in $\mu^{-1}(0)$. How can one characterize such geodesic lifts?